# Description and plot for every variable in R Markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown

I have a dataframe `data`of `n`observations of several numeric and factor variables. I would like to produce a html report in which `class` and  `describe` are reported and a histogram (`qplot`or `ggplot`) is plotted for every variable.

1. How can I do that?
2. Is it possible in R Markdown to produce an automatic header preceding every variable analysis?

Thank you for your help.

Corrado

Comment: I'm quite optimistic that you could do that with the package `knitr`. check out the [website](http://yihui.name/knitr/) and go through the examples. If you are still stuck, I think you have to update your question a little: Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: First question: I don't know how to incorporate `ggplot`or `qplot`in a function with `class`and `describe` and to apply it to the entire database. Second question: actually I have no idea how to do that, but I'll check the examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put a loop in your R chunks in Markdown files. Something like that for example :

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
```

This is an introductory sentence with absolutely no interest.

```{r, results="asis", eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
data(cars)
for (varname in names(cars)) {
  var <- cars[,varname]
  cat(paste0("<h2>",varname,"</h2>"))
  cat(paste0("Class : <pre>",class(var),"</pre>"))
  cat("Summary : <pre>")  
  print(summary(var))
  cat("</pre>")  
  if (is.numeric(var)) print(qplot(var, binwidth=diff(range(var))/30))
}
```

This is an astonishing conclusion.
````

Which gives the following result : http://rpubs.com/juba/mdloop